# Coldfusion: authenticating hashed password

Tags: hash, coldfusion

I have a login authentication system, the passwords in the database are stored as SHA-384. The following login script does nothing, when I include the Hash function. Where am I going wrong?

I'm using MSSQL Server 2008 R2, Coldfusion 10.

**loginform.cfm**

```
<cfif IsDefined("FORM.email")>
  <cfset redirectLoginSuccess="admin.cfm">
  <cfset redirectLoginFailed="login.cfm">
  <cfquery  name="UserAuth" datasource="sql1007539">
  SELECT email,userPass FROM customers WHERE email=<cfqueryparam value="#FORM.email#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_clob" maxlength="255"> 
  AND userPass=<cfqueryparam value="#Hash(form.userPassword, "SHA-384")#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_clob" maxlength="255">
  </cfquery>
  <cfif UserAuth.RecordCount NEQ 0>
    <cftry>
      <cflock scope="Session" timeout="30" type="Exclusive">
        <cfset Session.Username=FORM.email>
        <cfset Session.UserAuth="">
      </cflock>
      <cfif IsDefined("URL.accessdenied") AND true>
        <cfset redirectLoginSuccess=URL.accessdenied>
      </cfif>
      <cflocation url="#redirectLoginSuccess#" addtoken="no">
      <cfcatch type="Lock">
      </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
  </cfif>
  <cflocation url="#redirectLoginFailed#" addtoken="no">
  <cfelse>
  <cfset LoginAction=CGI.SCRIPT_NAME>
  <cfif CGI.QUERY_STRING NEQ "">
    <cfset LoginAction=LoginAction & "?" & XMLFormat(CGI.QUERY_STRING)>
  </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Edit: The script works if no HASH functions are used.
Edit: I can also confirm the passwords are stored in SHA-384. I checked using the following HASH identifier: duncanwinfrey.com/tools/hashid/hash.php

**Edit 29/05/13**

**Code returns error,  when I remove the cfparam tag **

```
<cfquery  name="UserAuth" datasource="sql1007539">
  SELECT email,userPass FROM customers WHERE email="#FORM.email#" 
  AND userPass="#hash(form.userPassword, "sha-384")#"
  </cfquery>
```

**Error returned**
[image]

Comment: It does nothing? What do you see? Does it load? Can you submit it? Have you verified the params are coming into the server page? When you say it works without the hash, that means you get logged in successfully? If that's the cause, it is likely that your passwords aren't hashed in the database. Check your `customers` table: if you can read the passwords in plain text, then the passwords were never hashed. Calling a hash function on them before looking them up won't work. If you want them be hashed, you'll have to calculate the hash and store it back into the table.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the userPass field from the DB and comparing by eye to the result of calling hash() on the password? Often these problems are caused by the way the data is saved. For instance, if can either be in base64 or some other format. Try saving a password of 'password' then update your question with what you see in SQL vs what you get from CF's hash function. That may give us something to work with

Comment: @Patrick M, The form works if I use : userPass=<cfqueryparam value="#form.userPassword#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_clob" maxlength="255">
  </cfquery>. I can login with a dummy account which is stored in the DB with no encryption.

Comment: Check your `customers` table: can  you read the other account passwords or are they hashed?

Comment: They are hashed, just the one I added directly to the DB is not (dummy password).

Comment: Do what barnyr suggests then. Sign up a new account with a password of 'password' (or do whatever you do to make a non-dummy account) and report what the database says it is.

Comment: @ Patrick : I did as suggested, I can confirm the password is stored in hash. 

 A8B64BABD0ACA91A59BDBB7761B421D4F2BB38280D3A75BA0F21F2BEBC45583D446C598660C94CE680C47D19C30783A7

Comment: I can also confirm the passwords are stored in SHA-384. I checked using the following HASH identifier: http://duncanwinfrey.com/tools/hashid/hash.php

Comment: the hash you posted is also what I get when I dump Hash("password", "SHA-384") so that looks to be what CF is generating. is that also what the DB is storing? You could also replace the call to hash() in your querty with your string from above and see if it allows that one user to login. If it doesn't, then that's a sign it's to do with string comparison.

Comment: Have you compared what the result is of the DB doing a SHA-384 hash and CF doing the same is? IE: use a known password, and add it into the system. Pull its hash from the DB table. Use CF to likewise hash the same plain-text password. Compare the results of the two. There can be variations in how the things are encoded / stored which you'll need to marry-up between the two systems.

Comment: What is the datatype of your SQL customers.userPass? Is it also a CLOB? Does it need to be a CLOB? Try testing without the cfqueryparam and see if it's an issue with your cfsqltype. Change your query to ...AND userPass= '#Hash(form.userPassword, "SHA-384")#'. See if you can get it to recognize your hashed password that way. Don't forget to change it back before you push it to production.

Comment: Shawn, thank you for your suggestion, when I use double quotes and remove cfqueryparam instead of single quotes, it returns an error, please see added photo.

Comment: You've got a clob with maxlength 255? Where I come from those are called varchars (the point of a clob is for _large_ strings; 255 chars is not large for a db) - but in any case both bits are wrong. SHA produces fixed width ASCII output - for SHA-384 your database column should be a `char(96)` and your qp just use `cf_sql_char` - there is no need for maxlength attribute because the function will produce 96 characters every time.

Comment: p.s. if you haven't already, put the queryparams back - they stop the SQL injection that is otherwise possible through the email field, and enable the use of a single parametrised execution plan (which will be better than having one for every user).

Comment: *Yes they are stored correctly* You need to be more specific about what troubleshooting steps you have tried ;-) Adam gave some very good suggestions about how to troubleshoot the problem. You should be able to use those to put together a solid [repro case](http://www.sscce.org/) you can include in your question. In the process, you might figure out the problem yourself. But even if you do not, posting an example that others can test independently will lead to a faster answer, because it eliminates the guesswork.

Comment: That error is caused by the double quotes. You need single quotes for a sql value. userPass='#Hash(form.userPassword, "SHA-384")#'  Again, make sure to put the cfqueryparam back in before you go to production. This will only help you troubleshoot. I'm still not sure why a password field needs to be a CLOB. Peter had a good suggestion with switching to char(), if you're able. What is the actual datatype of the password field in the database?

Comment: @ Shwan, thank you for your input, I still have no luck. I have removed the CLOB etc, I think it might be an encoding issue. I will post my findings.

Comment: @ Shawn: The datatype is a varchar(100).

Comment: I couldn't type much in the comments, so I left more details below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working with help from (*agx*) from the Experts Exchange forum. It turns out it was human error on my part. I had an extra space in my insert query of the registration process and also set the encoding to UTF-8:

> '(space)#hash(form.password, "sha-384" ,'UTF-8')#'

I changed the password type to `char(96)`, and amended the `cfqueryparam`, as suggested. Thank you all for your help and guidance. Below is troubleshooting code, I used to help me figure this out:

**Entered an email and password of an existing entry, to grab record from the db:**

```
<cfset form.email = "some known email">
<cfset form.userPassword = "real password before hashing">

<!--- ONLY match on email ---->
<cfquery name="qGetData" ....>
     SELECT  * 
     FROM    yourTable
     WHERE   email =<cfqueryparam value='#FORM.email#' 
                            cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery>

<!--- Checking to see if the password is hashed or is in clear text --->
<cfdump var="#qGetData#">
```

**Hashed the clear text password and compared it to the db value.**

```
<cfset newhash = hash(form.userPassword,'SHA-384')>
<cfif compare(newHash, qGetData.userPass) eq 0>
    SAME
<cfelse>
    DIFFERENT
</cfif>
```

**At first sight the values looked the same. To make sure both the stored password in db and password from the login form were the same, the following code was used:**

```
<cfoutput>
   db |#qGetData.userPass#|<br>
   form |#hash(form.userPassword,'SHA-384')#|<br>
</cfoutput>
```

I then used a [handy website to compare the outputs](http://www.diffnow.com/). The results were the same again. After all this hard work, it turned there was an extra space in front of the `#hash(...)#`.

Comment: RE: *The results were the same* Good job. One correction though, if there was an extra leading space, then the values were NOT the same. That online tool ignores white space by default, so you would not see the differences unless you change the default options.

Comment: I can't even count how many times I've banged my head on the wall over unexpected leading/trailing spaces in the database or even worse special characters that transferred over from copy/pasting from Word. Grrrr....   Glad you got it fixed Caludia.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with the encoding issue. I believe CLOB/BLOB are typically Oracle or DB2 datatypes and not native to MS SQL Server. I don't think you can assign CLOB/BLOB as a datatype in SQL Server. When you're passing a cf_sql_clob into the cfqueryparam, it's using the JDBC driver to try to convert to text or varchar(max) when it talks back to SQL Server. Something may be getting lost in translation. Since you're connecting to a SQL Server, try passing the correct datatype to the cfqueryparam. Look at the properties of the database columns for email and userPass. You should be able to set the cfsqltype to something like cf_sql_char or cf_sql_varchar. I'm kind of surprised the query isn't throwing an error, but the error may be getting masked by the datatype conversions, and it's simply not returning any results.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378813(v=sql.105).aspx

EDIT:
Try changing your query to:

```
SELECT email,userPass FROM customers 
WHERE email = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.email#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="255"> 
AND userPass = <cfqueryparam value="#Hash(form.userPassword, "SHA-384")#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="255">
```

Comment: Sorry about the edits. It kept escaping my cfqueryparams and wouldn't let me format the code right. :-S

Comment: Thank you Shawn, I've put this into action.

Comment: Shawn I've posted the solution in the answers. :-)

Answer (score 1):

When using double quotes, the value is parsed as an object (table, columns, etc).
Always stick with the cfqueryparam, which is secure and fast.

Try adding a third argument to the Hash function which forces a different encoding; eg:

```
<cfquery  name="UserAuth" datasource="sql1007539">
  SELECT email,userPass FROM customers WHERE email=<cfqueryparam value="#FORM.email#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_clob" maxlength="255"> 
  AND userPass=<cfqueryparam value="#Hash(form.userPassword, "SHA-384", "UTF-8")#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_clob" maxlength="255">
  </cfquery>
```

Note the UTF-8 argument. Common encodings are: ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-11 (Latin9).

Gl !

Comment: I believe the encoding argument in the CF hash function is buggy and doesn't always work as advertised. I know it used to be. Don't know if that's still the case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a typeo or this is your code directly copy and pasted:

You are effectively bombing your cfquery tag with the double quotes inside the hash function of the value attribute.

- You have this: value="#Hash(form.userPassword, "SHA-384")#"
- Replace it with this: value="#Hash(form.userPassword, 'SHA-384')#"

Please note the Single quotes around the SHA-384 value. This should fix your problem.

Comment: Nope, it's perfectly valid to `"#do("this")#"` - it works fine and does not cause any errors. If you're crazy you can even do stuff like `"#"#"this"#"#"` and it still functions, (even if it's tricky for human eyes to follow).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Brett, still no luck after trying your suggestion.

Comment: (p.s. Just noticed the syntax colouring issue in the question that may have triggered this response - so to clarify, that's a flaw in SO's syntax highligher, which doesn't know CFML and thus doesn't know it should treat the contents of the hash as an expression.)