# coldfusion: decrypt password with laravel

Tags: php, encryption, coldfusion, laravel-8

i have project that converting from coldfusion to php laravel 8 project. The login system coldfusion uses encryption for the password before storing the data to database with following code:

```
<!--- check if the user has basic select privileges --->
<cfset keys = "mykey">
<cfset pwddd = "#form.pwd#">
<cfset encrypted = encrypt(pwddd, keys)>
```

To login to the same database with existing user and password, i think i need to know how to decrypt the password stored to database with laravel way. But, is there any way to decrypt the password encrypted by coldfusion with laravel 8? Or do you have a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: Is this the solution for it.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796133/coldfusion-authenticating-hashed-password)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796133/coldfusion-authenticating-hashed-password]

Comment: First, passwords should be hashed not encrypted. Second, that's not even a standard encryption algorithm. It's the deprecated CFMX_COMPAT which is extremely insecure.